# Change state of a property automaticly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hi guys im kinda new on asp.net mvc and im trying to do something that is kinda confusing me, i have a model called desafio(challenge) and that challenge has a avaliation property that should change after 24 hours my doubts is how can i do that where should i do that, should i create a new controller? i need something to control i already searched a lot and didnt find a proper way to do that i need some lights.

Do i need to create a function where i can change the state, but when should i call the function im a little bit confused.

Here is my challenge model

```
  public class Desafio
{
    public int DesafioId { get; set; }

    public string TipoTrabalho { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int TipoAvaliacaoId { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoAvaliacao TipoAvaliacao { get; set; }       
    public decimal valor { get; set; }
    public int Visualizacoes { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public int IdSolucaoVencedora { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

because my question is kinda confused i will explain it better, what i need here is to change my property value on my challenge(Desafio) depending on my system timer. For exemple when pass 4 hours it changes automaticly from "inAvaluation" to "Closed" there should be a way to implemente this but i didnt find anything yet

Comment: How are you using this model? Is it stored in a database? Maybe you can add an expiration-field which indicates how 'old' its values are. But I need more information about how the application works (the context)

Comment: can we talk on chat?

Comment: I'd suggest you to provide more information so every stackoverflow user can help you :-)